# Sesame concurrent connections

Tags: sesame

I am using Sesame RDFStore. I was wondering how many incoming concurrent requests (connections) sesame can support.

Is there any Jetty/Sesame configuration that I can change to support more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of concurrent connections to the webapp is determined by Jetty, not Sesame. Sesame itself supports multithreaded access on most of its backends, so you're really only limited by the number of resources each thread consumes (e.g. you might run out of memory if you have to serialize X large query results concurrently).